Python Flask after form is validated execute javascript or rerender a page
In my project I have route which after submitting the form takes about 10 sec to generate results and then redirect to another route. I would like in meanwhile when this operations take place  somehow page re render  with new info so I can let know user to wait ? If not I have JS which  after clicking on submit button does x. The problem is even if form is not validated it triggers every time. How can I have it to check as well if form is validated ? Thank You
I tried with sockets but it seems they can't handle this as well.
Example code:
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = Form()
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
        return redirect(url_for('result'))
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)

@app.route('/result')
def result():
    a = function1)
    b = function2()
    c = function3()
    return render_template('ulala.html', a=a , b=b ,c=c)

Do I have to do something like fake button? Where button will not send form but will trigger JS and then actually call function to submit ?
